# batch delete css selectors identified by dust me selectors?

Tags: css, firefox-addon

The dust me selectors FireFox plugin identifies unused css selectors. For large css files and many files, the manual deletion of the unused selectors is time consuming. Is there a tool that can automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Spider controls of http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/348687/1104268448-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/348687/1104268448-My-Desktop.png)